# Casting one class to member of other class of different type

Tags: c#, object, casting

I want to assign a value to member A.Edits which should be same as A. I have tried casting one class to other but its not working. Only in 'A.Edits' I want to assign value rest A.Errors, & A.Warnings I dont want to touch. I am getting result set in Edit class B.

I have got two user defined class A & B of ClaimEditModel & Edit type which are as below-
    Class Definition is as below-

```
public class ClaimEditModel()
{
    Edits = new List<EditInfo>();
    Errors = new List<EditRuleError>();
    Warnings = new List<EditRuleError>();
}

public class Edit
{
    public int EditLevel;
    public int EditNumber;
    public string EditType;
    public List<Field> PrimaryFields;
    public string Rule;
}

ClaimEditModel A = new ClaimEditModel();
Edit B = new Edit();
```

Can anyone please suggest.

Something like this I have tried:

```
A.Edits =  new Edit(){ edits = B };
```

Comment: your posted code will not compile

Comment: Edits is a list of EditInfo, you cannot cast it to Edit type...

Comment: Posted code is not correct.

Comment: The class Edit, doesn't have a attribute edits?!

Comment: I think you want to map EditInfo Class to edit Objects and Add to Edits.

Answer (score 0):

It's a confusing question, but I *think* you just want to add an instance of `Edit` to the list in `A`. So you can do this:

```
A.Edits.Add(B);
```

---

Your class definitions in your code are also invalid, though this may just be a mistake while writing your question. My answer is based on the assumption that your *real* definition for `ClaimEditModel` is as follows, if it isn't then you need to change that too:

```
public class ClaimEditModel()
{
    public List<EditInfo> Edits = new List<EditInfo>();
    public List<EditRuleError> Errors = new List<EditRuleError>();
    public List<EditRuleError> Warnings = new List<EditRuleError>();
}
```

Comment: @Rahul: True, but the OP is suggesting his problem is with setting the value. OP has not mentioned an issue with class definitions, so we *could* assume the definitions in the questions are just missing some code. Or maybe you are right and OP has problems with that too... I guess we can only wait for clarification on that

Comment: It's a guess not an answer. Should be comment instead.

Comment: @Reniuz: I don't know... I think it's a fairly reasonable assumption to be honest. The question is clearly focused on setting the value, and there is no mention whatsoever about class definition problems. It's not uncommon to have to read between the lines with questions on SO, especially from inexperienced users like the OP

Comment: Well I agree on what saying. It is my personal opinion, but comments on unclear question forces OP to edit question and add more details to get an answer. When the issue is clear in the question answering it we will leave question related to answer. Now if you are correct, OP get's what it needs and accepts the answer then only from the answer you will know what was the real issue in the question. I am thinking how this will be disappointing for future readers who is looking for an answer on casting issue (and the title is about that)

Comment: @Reniuz: yeah,  a fair point. If the OP somehow makes a comment, or accepts the answer, I will tidy up the question to make it clear for future readers